# Using Jquery to get JSON objects from local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-files

I'm trying to get a list of JSON objects (products) from a local file using Jquery and store all the objects in a single array called allItems.  The file is co-located in the same directory as the code, and it's called "allItems.json".  Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
function getAllSupportedItems(){
    var allItems = new Array();
    $.getJSON("allItems.json",
         function(data){
             $.each(data.items, 
             function(item){
                 allItems.push(item);
             });
         });
    return allItems;
}
```

Based on this example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: You didn't explicitly state what your question/problem is, but from the code I can see that you're mixing sync/async concepts. You either need to completely go sync or async.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For `getAllSupportedItems` to be able to return any items, the AJAX call needs to run synchronously.

`getJSON` translates to the following asynchronous call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

Asynchronous is the default. You therefore need to explicitly change your request to a synchronous one:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback,
  async: false
});
```

An alternative is to rethink the way you use `getAllSupportedItems` and make it into an asynchronous utility:

```
function getAllSupportedItems(callback){
    $.getJSON("allItems.json",
         function(data){
             var allItems = [];
             $.each(data.items, 
             function(item){
                 allItems.push(item);
             });
             callback(allItems);
             // callback(data.items); should also work
         });
}
```

---

#### Update

When I initially wrote this answer, jQuery didn't have built-in Deferred support. It is a lot more concise and flexible to do something like this today:

```
function getAllSupportedItems( ) {
    return $.getJSON("allItems.json").then(function (data) {
        return data.items;
    });
}

// Usage:
getAllSupportedItems().done(function (items) {
    // you have your items here
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work it says getAllSupportedItems.done is not a function

Comment: @Even Which version of jQuery did you try it with? It's gotta be 1.6+ I think. Also, you try evaluating: `$.Deferred`. If it's `undefined`, you don't have Promise support.

Comment: This is how I load my local JSON files: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079631/dynamically-reload-local-javascript-source-json-data/17736371#17736371). I don't use jQuery though.

Answer (score 0):

How are you using this?  If you're expecting the main function ("getAllSupportedItems") to *return* the array you make, well that won't work.  The `$.getJSON` function is *asynchronous*, and so the handler won't actually build the array until after the outer function has returned.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me, but being a js n00b, what mechanism do I use to ensure it gets loaded before returning?

Comment: What you need to do is arrange for the action to happen after the response is recieved.  Look over the answer from Ates Goral.