# backbone model fetch JSON element by ID

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am using backbone for the first time and I am really struggling to get it to function correctly with a JSON data file.

I have a model Like so:

```
window.Test = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults: {  
    id: null,
    name: null,
},

url: function() {
    return 'json/test.json/this.id';
  },

initialize: function(){  

}
});
```

When a test item is clicked I then try to bring up the details of the pacific model that was clicked by doing

```
testDetails: function (id) {


    var test = new Test();
    test.id = id;
    test.fetch({ success: function(data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data))}});
},
```

However this does not work, I am unable to correctly say "get the JSON element with the passed ID"

Can anyone please show me how to correctly structure the models URL to pull the element with the ID.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're treating your JSON data file like a call to a server. That won't work and it's the reason you're getting a 404. If you're accessing a file locally, you have to load the file first. You can do this with jQuery using the .getJSON() method, or if the file's static, just load it into memory with a script block (though you'll probably need to assign a var in the file). Most likely, you'll use jQuery. An example of this can be found here:

[Using Jquery to get JSON objects from local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792423/using-jquery-to-get-json-objects-from-local-file).

If this is an array of JSON, you can load the array into a collection, and use the "at" method to access the particular element by id. If it's entirely JSON, you'll have to create a custom parser.

Answer (score 0):

your url is incorrect for one. you are returning the literal string 'this.id'. you probably want to do something more along the lines of

```
url: function () {
    return 'json/test.json/' + this.id;
}
```

Comment: In Backbone, you use the `.get()` method to access model properties. `this.id` will return `undefined`

Comment: Hi Thanks, I have changed it now however I get the error GET http://localhost/backbone/json/test.json/2 404 (Not Found)

Comment: How would I tell it to get a JSON element with the ID given

Comment: @jackwanders this.id works fine when being referenced from within the model itself. you are correct however that using get would be the proper use from outside of the model.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by fixing your `url` function:

```
url: function() {
    return 'json/test.json/' + this.get('id');
}
```

The way you have it now, every fetch request, regardless of the model's `id`, is going to `/json/test.json/test.id`

Comment: Hi Thanks, I have changed it now however I get the error GET localhost/backbone/json/test.json/2 404 (Not Found)

Comment: In that case, there's most likely an issue with routing on your server, or your `url` is still incorrect. I can't help more without knowing more about how your backend is set up